# Find the probability of Filium (child) that are dark (and) heterozygote

Tags: genetics

Two mice are crossed and both are dark and heterozygote. Find the probability of their filium(children) dark (and) heterozygote in F1.

Here's what our teacher explained:

[image]

I don't understand. I thought it would be 1/2.

Comment: You are correct, the teacher must have made a typo

Comment: Well, she insisted in her answer and said that this is quite a difficult exercise, but if we do it in my way it is so easy.

Comment: What is the entire question? Is there more to it than what you posted?

Comment: No, it's not. I've posted the whole question.

Comment: Is hair color inherited in a Mendelian way?